# What does "drew solace" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Reading this [**article**](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/florida-frisco-americans-flock-movies-110752689.html), there is a line,

> In North Carolina, college students whose university experience was rocked by the pandemic **drew solace** from watching a basketball game between UNC-Chapel Hill and Duke University men's teams, only the second game this season with spectators.

Neither dictionaries nor googling helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[draw](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw):

> to bring, take, or pull out, as from a receptacle or source.

[solace](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/solace):

> comfort in sorrow, misfortune, or trouble; alleviation of distress or discomfort.

*draw* is used in a somewhat metaphorical sense, but otherwise the sentence has no hidden meaning - the students *drew* (ie. obtained, as if by drawing water from a source) *solace* (ie. comfort) from watching the game.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't this part grammatically strange?

Comment: @Kentaro why do you think it is?

Comment: Ah...it's my mistake I thought "pandemic drew solace" is a set word.

Comment: @ Kentaro  "college students ... drew solace"

Answer (score 2):

"Solace" is emotional comfort. This sentence says students found that comfort watching basketball. It's idiomatic English to say they "drew solace" from the experience. Here "drew" is the past tense of "draw (out)".

For examples, see https://ludwig.guru/s/drawing+solace